# Window resize and document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this working code for an almost full height slideshow:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height(); 
    var headerHeight = $(".navbar").height(); 
    $('#slideshow-wrapper, #slideshow, #slideshow .overlay, #slideshow #slogan-wrapper, #slideshow .overlay').height(winHeight - 145);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

The code works, you can check it out here:

http://leda.rewind9.com/

How can I wrap this code around a document ready function in order to avoid the initial flicker the browser does when its calculating the #slideshow height?

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var winHeight = $(window).height(); 
        var headerHeight = $(".navbar").height(); 
        $('#slideshow-wrapper, #slideshow, #slideshow .overlay, #slideshow #slogan-wrapper, #slideshow .overlay').height(winHeight - 145);
    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

But the flicker won't go away. In order to reproduce the problem, just reload the page and check how the slideshow text "hangs" before getting centered.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Give your container some minimum height - that will prevent any flicker. Its essentially kind-of unavoidable anyway since the JS gets executed right after it is loaded, meaning it could be delayed slightly. Just make sure to set a fallback height in your CSS (like, say `80vh`). If you set the `height` property, JS will overwrite it anyway.

Comment: I think that the problem is the images doesn't load when you execute the script. Try to use `$(window).on('load')` instead, that it waits to load all resources in the page to execute the code inside.

Comment: @somethinghere Giving the container a height kind of fixes the issue (it makes the flicker less obvious). The thing is that it's kind of sad there's no fix for this.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I think it's a problem with several heights trying to be calculated at the same time, images load fine.

Comment: Like many mention, image loading can fix this. The issue is that you do not know the height until its loaded and you need _something_ in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Johann I trust you that images load fine, but when you make `$(document).ready()` images still not loaded yet, because is the event that means DOM tree is ready, but the resources doesn't loaded yet (images, videos, script files in the bottom, etc)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, quick and easy jQuery specific fix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('body').show();
});
```

Just make sure to add "display:none" to your body tag. It works, but keeps me wonder what happens if JS is disabled.